# Automated git pull on system boot on raspberry pi

Tags: python, git, automation, raspberry-pi

I'm using a raspberry pi zero with jessie lite installed and I want to pull from a github repository on system boot. 
I have written a python script

```
os.system("(cd ~/Exchange/KneeJointMonitoring && git pull)")
```

which works fine when executed manually. 
For automation I have used rc.local, where I have added

```
sudo python /home/pi/Exchange/KneeJointMonitoring/AutoPull.py &
```

which should also work, since another script (called after the above one) is started on boot. 
I have also added a SSH key to github and added it on the raspberry pi following this (and the linked) tutorials for machine users:
https://developer.github.com/v3/guides/managing-deploy-keys/

Afterwards, I ran

```
ssh -T git@github.com
```

which was successfully. 
Anyways, my Pi is not pulling the repo in startup, what am I missing? Can somebody help?

Comment: It might be that *~* is pointing to different location, since you run it as *root*. Or the *root* doesn't have the key. Or you don't have a connection yet. Anyways, you should redirect your output to some log file and check that.

Comment: thanks pacholik, your input helped to solve the problem :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to the input of @pacholik, I was able to solve the problem:
First I got rid of the ~ in command line ran by the python file (not sure if that was a problem). 
The major change was:

```
git remote set-url origin https://{username}:{password}@github.com/{username}/{project}.git
```

After the next reboot, the programm was updated :)